# How to implement Google Analytics in SAPUI5?

Tags: google-analytics, sapui5

I created a Google Analytics account and copied the tracking code to the index.html page as per the following post:

https://blogs.sap.com/2016/04/25/google-analytics-sap-fiori/

Although, this seems not to be working as it is not tracking any data, not even page views.

I am using the SAP Web IDE to implement this.

What am I missing? Thank you.

Comment: When did you create the account?

Comment: Yesterday. Why?

Comment: it can take up to 24  hours for a new Google analytics account to start tracking data. https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1009683?hl=en

Comment: Oh, wow, that is too much time but ok.

Comment: Just figure out when yesterday that you created it and then check the link i posted there are a number of things that can cause issues with new accounts.

Comment: You are not going to believe this. I just found out the reason for not getting any data from the page was because I had an add blocker extension enabled. Took me quite some time to remember that.